# VLFeat SIFT descriptor

Tags: c++, image-processing, sift, vlfeat

I'm reading [this code](https://github.com/sunnala/nise/blob/75b1aa896919ac1143e4e071d4fd38181d2335ba/extract/sift-wrapper.cpp) about how to extract SIFT features using VLFeat. In particular the descriptor relative to the keypoint `key` with direction `angles` is saved in `f.desc`:

```
                vl_sift_calc_keypoint_descriptor(filt, &f.desc[0], key, angles[q]) ;

                BOOST_FOREACH(float &v, f.desc) {
                    /*
                    v = round(v * SIFT_RANGE);
                    if (v > SIFT_RANGE) v = SIFT_RANGE;
                    */
                    v *= 2;
                    if (v > 1.0) v = 1.0;
                }
```

What I don't understand is the `FOREACH` loop: why each descriptor value is doubled? And why the max value is set to `1.0`?